# Why does setting rotation with Quaternion (vs Euler) result in extremely fast angular velocity? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Question**

I have a Unity project ([Github repo](https://github.com/starkindustries/UnityRotationTest/tree/simplified)) where I flip my sprite 180 degrees on the y-axis and then set its angular velocity to 10. I set the object's rotation's y-axis in the inspector:

[image: initial rotation]

I use this script to set its angular velocity:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationTest : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Current rotation: " + transform.rotation.ToString());              
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.angularVelocity = 10f;
    }
}
```

I expect the spin to be relatively slow. However, I notice that the sprite begins spinning extremely fast, which is unexpected.

To debug, I log the initial rotation to the console with this line:

`Debug.Log("Current rotation: " + transform.rotation.ToString());`

This outputs: `Current rotation: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. I assume these are the [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) values x, y, z, and w respectively. To confirm this I reset the transform rotation to (0, 0, 0) in the inspector and via script I set the rotation to a new Quaternion value:

`transform.rotation = new Quaternion(x: 0f, y: 1f, z: 0f, w: 0f);`

And indeed the same extremely fast spinning occurs. However, this fast spin does not occur if instead I set the rotation with Euler angles like this:

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x: 0f, y: 180f, z: 0f);`

Instead of spinning really fast, the sprite spins nice and slowly as I expect. When I log the Euler value to the console, the output is identical to the Quaternion value's output. Yet the resulting spins are very different.

Why does this happen?

**Demo**

I modified the simple project above to use two buttons to further demonstrate the problem. Here it is in action ([Github link](https://github.com/starkindustries/UnityRotationTest) and [web app](https://starkindustries.github.io/UnityRotationTest/)).

There is a spaceship and two buttons: a Euler button (top) and a Quaternion button (bottom). When the Euler button is pressed, the rotation is set with Euler values and the ship rotates slowly. When the Quaternion button is pressed, the rotation is set with the Quaternion values and the ship rotates insanely fast.

[image]

The full script is below. The Euler button triggers the `DidPressEulerButton()` function. The Quaternion button triggers the `DidPressQuaternionButton()` function.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationTest : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Current rotation: " + transform.rotation.ToString());              
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.angularVelocity = 10f;
    }

    public void DidPressEulerButton()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x: 0f, y: 180f, z: 0f);
        Debug.Log("Quaternion.Euler(x: 0f, y: 180f, z: 0f): " + transform.rotation.ToString());
    }

    public void DidPressQuaternionButton()
    {
        transform.rotation = new Quaternion(x: 0f, y: 1f, z: 0f, w: 0f);
        Debug.Log("Quaternion(x: 0f, y: 1f, z: 0f, w: 0f): " + transform.rotation.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Links and Resources**

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-ctor.html
- Github Main repo (buttons) https://github.com/starkindustries/UnityRotationTest
- Github Simplified Branch (no buttons)
  https://github.com/starkindustries/UnityRotationTest/tree/simplified
- Web app https://starkindustries.github.io/UnityRotationTest/

**Unity version:** 2019.2.0b2 Personal

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't create Quaternions directly with `new`. Even in docs you find: `y Y component of the Quaternion. Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.` Usually, static Quaternion methods are all you need. I also find it weird that you're modifying the rotation of the transform and not the rigidbody, is that on purpose?

Comment: It looks bug I guess because there is no acceleration of you given code. that button just set angle up to target object. but weird.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments! @Iggy, yes it is on purpose. I'm modifying the transform because I want to flip my sprite to face a different direction (left instead of right). Modifying the rigidbody2D's rotation will only rotate it along the z-axis; it can't flip it. I'm trying to find documentation that discourages using `new` for Quaternions; Unity shows using the constructor in its docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-ctor.html

Comment: @Iggy, also, setting the rotation with `new Quaternion` is just another symptom of the problem. I did this to further demonstrate what was happening. If you simply set the transform's rotation's y-axis to 180 in the inspector as I mentioned at the start of my question (and remove all button logic) then this behavior still occurs.

Comment: This seems to be a conflict between the `Transform` and the `RigidBody2D` component. I don't know how the RigidBody handles the rotation internally but it seems like: If you set Y to 180° then the RigidBody would actually have to rotate the object in the oposite direction .. which it doesn't. So elternating every frame you rotate a bit in Z+ then in Z- ... you can bring Unity to totally crush if you hit the Pause button in the correct moment ;)